# List files recursively in Kotlin

Tags: file, kotlin, recursion, directory

to list files in a directory with kotlin, i used list() and listFiles() functions:

```
File("/tmp").list().forEach { println(it) }
File("/tmp").listFiles().forEach { println(it) }
```

but, how can i list files recursively?

Answer (score 99):

Use one of [`.walk(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/walk.html), [`.walkBottomUp()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/walk-bottom-up.html) or [`.walkTopDown()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/walk-top-down.html) extensions for `File`, which differ only in the order in which the files appear and all produce a [`FileTreeWalk`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/-file-tree-walk/index.html), that implements [`Sequence<File>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/):

```
File("/tmp").walkTopDown().forEach { println(it) }
```